# Abelian Kummer Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

A field extension of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \sqrt[n]{\beta})$ where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity and $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is called a Kummer extension.

Even though $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \sqrt[n]{\beta})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ and 
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ are Galois and Abelian it is not always the case that 
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \sqrt[n]{\beta})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois.

Question: If $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \sqrt[n]{\beta})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois will it be Abelian ?

Comment: How could $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \sqrt[n]{\beta})/\mathbb{Q}$ not be Galois?  Isn't it the splitting field of $x^n - \beta$?

Comment: @SpamIAm $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ so it is possible that $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^i$ will send $\beta$ to some other element.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. $\beta$ isn't necessarily in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @SpamIAm Yes, as you point out if it is in $\mathbb{Q}$ then it will be Galois.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It can be dihedral: take $n=3$ and $\beta=2$ to get the splitting field of $x^3-2$ as your field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \sqrt[n]{\beta})$. The Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_3$ (thought of as the dihedral group of order $6$) containing a transposition (complex conjugation) and therefore equal to $S_3$.

Comment: Nice answer. Note explicity that if $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{2})=\zeta\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta$ and $\tau(\zeta)=\zeta^2$, $\tau(\sqrt[3]{2})=\sqrt[3]{2}$ then $\sigma \tau (\sqrt[3]{2})=\zeta\sqrt[3]{2}$ but  $\tau \sigma  (\sqrt[3]{2})=\zeta^2\sqrt[3]{2}$